# VBA Selenium Button Submit Issue

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to build code that will go to the website "https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com", enter a string in the search field, and submit the button to get results (which I will eventually scrape and save in my excel file).

However, I cannot get the button to submit. Any iteration that I've tried results in submitting the delete text X that appears after I've entered my text. Below is my code:

```
Sub GetScores()
Dim bot As New WebDriver

' URL to get data from
bot.Start "Chrome", "https://testmysite.thinkwithgoogle.com"
bot.Get "/"

' Eventually loop through websites, for now just use example
Dim str As String
str = "www.google.com"

'Paste str into webpage

bot.FindElementByName("pagespeed-input").SendKeys (str)

bot.FindElementByClass("pagespeed__submit").Submit
```

And here is the html code from the website:

```
<div class="pagespeed " data-component="PageSpeed" >
    <form class="pagespeed__form" action="">
      <input type="hidden" name="pagespeed-locale" id="" value="en_us">
      <input type="url" name="pagespeed-input" class="pagespeed__input" placeholder="Enter your website URL" tabindex="-1" autofocus >
      <button type="submit" class="pagespeed__submit pagespeed__submit--disabled"  data-gtm-id="smbhub-url-entry" disabled>Test now</button>
    </form>
    <div class='pagespeed__error'></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Did you try `Click` instead of `Submit`?

Comment: I did, and I would get an error message. The version above is the only one I've gotten to actually accomplish a button click/submit, it's just the wrong one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`bot.FindElementByXPath("//button[@type='submit']").Click`

instead of using

`bot.FindElementByClass("pagespeed__submit").Submit`